# How do I connect OBIEE 11g and NoSQL ?

Tags: report, database-connection, data-transfer, obiee, oracle-nosql

I need a method by which I can connect OBIEE 11g and NoSQL. I need to transfer the connects in NoSQL to OBIEE reports. NoSQL is a software that is used for storage of data using key and values. How do I go about this? How do I connect the database?

Comment: NoSQL is a class of database/datastore software. Which specific software are you looking to connect to from OBIEE?

Answer (score 1):

For MongoDB and Cassandra, there are commercial ODBC drivers available from Oracle's connectivity partner: https://blogs.datadirect.com/2015/05/oracle-obiee-odi-meet-nosql-mongodb.html